# Update module content by email trigger?

Tags: emails, custom-module

I'm wondering if it's possible to write the equivalent of a "3 most recent Tweets" module, but for a Listserv mailing list, and where to begin?

If the system can be somehow made to read email, I think the problem is solved: subscribe the system to the listserv, with cron job parse received email (spam/malicious/correct) and extract desired bit, update module content.  But I didn't find any descriptions of similar setups, anything triggering Joomla or similar cms by email.

My title reflects the fact that I other approaches to the stated problem are even less likely to be practical/reliable, e.g. with cron job outside of Joomla check the listserv online archive, and update database field used by the display module. And I don't think there's an RSS feed for list-serv, and if so I have no idea how to make a module read that.  Maybe I overlook an obvious approach.

I didn't find a tag for this post covering the 'trigger' part of it (rather central).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to read mailbox from php script (so joomla extension too).

**What you should to do**:

- create CLI application to read emails and save last 3 in database/file
- add this application as CRON job
- create a module that will read database/file for those last emails

That way you will keep performance consuming task outside of Joomla but still be available to use Joomla framework, database etc.

#### Interesting links:

- [Reading mailbox from PHP](http://www.backslash.gr/content/blog/webdevelopment/8-check-your-email-with-php-and-imap)
- [Creating a Joomla CLI application](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_create_a_stand-alone_application_using_the_Joomla!_Platform)
- [Create a simple Joomla 3.x module](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module)